# Running MATLAB scripts from Sublime Text 3 without opening new instances

Tags: matlab, sublimetext

Good day,

I'm a rather inexperienced code writer, as my only experience is with MATLAB. However, I'll soon be learning all about Python, and I was recommended to use Sublime Text as an editor. In the mean time I'd like to get a feel for the editor by using it for my MATLAB tasks, and I'm having some trouble getting it to work so that I can run MATLAB scripts from Sublime, without having it opening up a new MATLAB instance every single time I run code. Would anyone be able to assist me with this?

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64, MATLAB 2013B, and Sublime Text 3. Right now I'm building my scripts using

```
{
 "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab.exe", "-nodesktop", "-nosplash",
        "-r", "\"run('$file')\""],
"selector": "source.m",
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"
 }
```

I'm not sure if I want the nodesktop, but I can just take that away. The point is that doing this opens up a new MATLAB screen every time, which takes a while and feels rather unnecessary.

I'd post this on the sublime forum, but it seems to be down for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/ down for you guys as well? The main site works, just the forum isn't for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run MATLAB as a server if you don't want a new instance for each call. I'm afraid I can't help you with the specifics, but you can have a look at the [MATLAB Automation Server](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html) page in the official documentation. And then find out how to call COM objects from Python, maybe using [PyWinAuto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/). Good luck.

P.S. Yes, the Sublime Text forum is down for me too. It has been down for five days now. Not good.